# Meaning of the sentence: "I am not particular"

Tags: meaning, idioms

I just stumbled into this phrase, coming from a person when describing themselves:

*"I am not particular"*

Because of (one of?) the meaning(s) of **particular**, I would've expected that sentence to mean something like "I am quite general". But from the conversation and other cues I believe that it meant the opposite thing.

Any help?

For context, it's from the novel *Bartleby, the Scrivener* by Herman Melville. There is a character who says this every now and then.

Answer (score 2):

**(one) ain't particular**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/particular) idiom

> One has no opinion or preference about something. ("Ain't" is a
>   nonstandard contraction that is considered very informal.)

Comment: Why use a very unusual construction (ain’t) instead of the standard one?

Comment: @Chappo - That's a direct quote from the dictionary entry. Who knows why they chose to list it that way?

Comment: @J.R. Yes, but why choose this unusual dictionary entry? Why not just cite the meaning of “particular” from a standard dictionary rather than search for an idiom the OP hadn’t asked for?

Comment: idiom tag present